# Verifying the identity $\frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x = \sin x \tan x$

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x = \sin x  * \tan x$

I have tried a few things and nothing works

---

### Left Side

$\frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x$

$1 - (\cos x)^2$

$1 - 1 + \frac{\cos 2x}{2}$

$ \frac{\cos 2x}{2}$

$ \frac{\cos x}{2} \times \frac{\cos}{2}$

... And I am out in left field!

Comment: That's an equation, not an identity.

Comment: @Agenog: I took the statement to mean, when defined, show that the two sides are equal.

Comment: Even then both sides tend to positive infinity from the left and negative infinity from the right, it is in fact an identity

Comment: @Triatticus It's *not* an identity, try $x=\pi / 4$ for example. P.S. It only became an identity now, once the OP changed the question 30 seconds ago.

Comment: I was talking about the first one not the second one, should have been clear on that. I thought the second was a failed algebraic step

Comment: I had a typo on the question... I had the correct formula but when I converted to the MathJax I put cos instead of tan on the right side. The original identity was still above it correct so I am sure it caused confusion.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood You had the correct answer posted even before the OP had asked the correct question ;-) Why did you delete it?

Comment: @dxiv: I'm at my university running back and forth helping students and I seen the comments here and thought I overlooked something. I think a lot of people were focusing on the problem in the question where I was only looking at the work the student did. My intent was not to delete but edit. Now that I am not being called upon, I see that it was right from the start.

Comment: I had added a response but seeing Faraad's much better hint I deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x = \frac{1- \cos^2 x}{\cos x}$$

Now I think you can finish.